# How to create Vertical progress bar in Bootstrap with

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have created horizontal progress bars, but how to create vertical progress bar? Here's my code, result is vertical progress bar, but they don't look like Bootstrap progress bars. I want to show percent, to be vertical and  their height of filling to be the result of query. They look like this:
http://prntscr.com/6l39cg It doesn't look good. I want to look like this:
[progress-bar](http://i1-scripts.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/bootstrap-progressbar-Stephan-Gross_3.png) And how to change height to be not 100%, but from 1 to 5. I've tried `aria-valuemax="5"` but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```html
<div id="tab2" class="mtab_content">
             <p>
    <?php foreach ($result_question1 as $row) {
         echo "$row->question";
     $percent=round("$row->answer",2); 
         
        ?> 
              <div class="vertical-progressbar">
         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" 
         style="width: 
         <?php echo round($percent,2); ?>%;">
         </div>
      <?php echo round($percent,2); } ?> %
    </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS is:

```css
.vertical-progressbar{
  width: 300px;
  height: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  
}
```

I found that solution, but height doesn't change in dependence of result of query:

```css
.progress-vertical {
    width: 20px;
    height: 200px !important;
    position: relative;
}
.progress-vertical .bar {
    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
    border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<?php foreach ($result_question1 as $row) {
         //echo "$row->question";
     $percent=round("$row->answer",2); 
        echo "<br/>";
     ?>
         <div class="progress progress-vertical progress-bar-success">
       <div class="bar" style="height: <?php echo round($percent,2); ?>%;"></div>
     
      <?php echo round($percent,2);  ?> %
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about using a CSS transform to rotate it 90 degrees.

```
.vertical-progressbar{
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: I want to be vertical, but they don't look like these in the link, they are in green color, but have to be in dependence of some percentage. I've written :   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"           
         style="width: 
         <?php echo round($percent,2); ?>%;">
         </div>     but it have to be height, as they are vertical, but when I change them to vertical, it does not work, no progress bars.